# Display another website's dynamic image on mine

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

**This statement works only on Opera :**

```
<img src="http://www.moviecovers.com/getjpg.html/LE%20CHARME%20DISCRET%20DE%20LA%20BOURGEOISIE.jpg"</img>
```

How should I do to make it work on Firefox ?

When I open straightly this URL on my browser : it displays the expected image but when I integrate this into my webpage it displays a 404 image error...

Is there a JavaScript/AJAX/Jquery way to load this can of image?

It seems the moviecovers wants a POST request...

Comment: it is not valid html. Do you not mean  `<img src="http://www.moviecovers.com/getjpg.html/LE%20CHARME%20DISCRET%20DE%20LA%20BOURGEOISIE.jpg"/>`

Comment: Also it has UTF8 code embedded - in a text editor I see LE%20CHARME%20DISCRET%20DE%20LA%20BO??URGEOISIE.jpg

Comment: is there not supposed to be a `?` after html how can you request a html file  and then carry on to the next directory using `/`

Comment: the actual resolved link is  `http://data.moviecovers.com/DATA/zipcache/LE%20CHARME%20DISCRET%20DE%20LA%20BOURGEOISIE.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is incorrect. It should be:

```
<img src="http://www.moviecovers.com/getjpg.html/LE%20CHARME%20DISCRET%20DE%20LA%20BOURGEOISIE.jpg" />
```

Assuming that wasn't a typo of course.

Comment: Your comment only appeared after I'd answered as I posted 19 seconds after you.

Answer (score 0):

If I fix the html and remove the UTF8 from the url, I get

`<img src="http://www.moviecovers.com/getjpg.html/LE%20CHARME%20DISCRET%20DE%20LA%20BOURGEOISIE.jpg" />`

which works by redirecting me to the larger version of

This one

[image: La Charme]
<sub>(source: [moviecovers.com](http://www.moviecovers.com/DATA/thumbs/films-c/LE%20CHARME%20DISCRET%20DE%20LA%20BOURGEOISIE.jpg))</sub>

That said:

> "The covers offered for viewing and
>   downloading by MOVIECOVERS.COM are
>   offered free and STRICTLY for use only
>   within the family - Any commercial use
>   or outside the limits of the framework
>   is completely prohibited - Abstracts
>   and posters the properties of their
>   respective rights holders."